# Can't figure out what is causing my performance bottleneck in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, profiling

My rails app, according to my heroku logs, is serving requests on average of about 1700 to 2500 milliseconds (this is the entire roundtrip). I used new relic to profile my app, and it seems that the majority of the request is not spent in my database but rather in the "Web Transaction" section of New Relic. It seems like the "Controller" category tends to be the slowest among requests, followed by the "SQL - SELECT" segment in the "Database" category.

I'm not quite sure what could be causing my performance bottleneck in my controllers, nor do I think I can dive deeper into new relic without paying for the premium version. I recently added indexes to the foreign keys of my application, although I do not think this made much of a difference in terms of database response times.

I know this is not enough information to figure out what is causing these bottlenecks, but I do not even know where to start or what info to give. If people could tell me what info is needed to diagnose these issues, then that would be helpful to me.

Comment: I've heard good reports of using [Rackamole](http://www.rackamole.com/home/screens) to find performance problems too, if New Relic isn't helpful enough another tool may come in handy.

Comment: The best thing would be to post the source code for the action profiled as slow. Also, remember that the bottleneck could be in the view if you're doing a lot of looping.

Comment: @SrdjanPejic I think that might be it. I do a lot of looping as well as associations in my views. Would moving these associations into instance methods in the model improve performance?

Comment: @JustinMeltzer if that's so, you're likely suffering from the n+1 problem. Wherever you're querying for the parent objects, add :include or :joins (but not both) to pre-load the associations.

Comment: Could you post code for one of the slow controller methods? Maybe rename/anonymize some classes if you are worried about security. I think it would help in this case to see if you are doing something wrong. You can see a lot in the logs as well (tail -f log/development.log) postgres reports the query time for each query.

Comment: For those who are interested, I moved all my javascript (and I have a lot!) to the bottom of my page and page load time feels so much faster now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Relic for Ruby includes a free, standalone developer mode. When running in RAILS_ENV=development, the New Relic gem adds a route that will show you a detailed profile for each request. Go to http://localhost:3000/newrelic after you hit your app a few times.

The profile includes time for each SQL query, as well as for components of your code. You can use [custom instrumentation](http://newrelic.com/docs/docs/custom-metric-collection) to break down big chunks of code into smaller segments (or individual methods) that get timed separately. This feature is a lot like the transaction traces you get in the paid Pro version, one major difference being that you wouldn't want to run the free dev mode in production.

(Full disclosure: I work for NR. Not many people know about the free dev mode, though, so I thought it was worth mentioning.)

You could potentially make Javascript loading appear even faster with something like [head.js](http://headjs.com/), which will load your JS files asynchronously and in parallel.

Comment: Oh interesting. Thanks! By the way I'm currently running New Relic as a Heroku addon, so I do not think I have access to it in development. Should I bundle it as a gem? Will this adversely impact the NR heroku addon?

Comment: Are you using the Cedar stack? The newrelic_rpm gem will be in your Gemfile. If you're on Bamboo, the plugin will be installed. Either way, you've got access to NR dev mode when you're running your site on your own machine. It it strictly local, doesn't communicate with newrelic.com.

Comment: I use Bamboo on heroku but I don't seem to have NR dev mode on my local development site. The `/newrelic` route doesn't exit. I installed the New Relic addon through heroku's command line interface, and I never pull the production code down to development, so it would make sense that it doesn't exist on my local machine. What am I missing?

Comment: if I add `newrelic_rpm` to my gemfile and then push it up to production, will that interfere with the plugin that was already installed on production through the heroku CLI?

Comment: I don't recommend mixing plugin and gem. You could add the gem in the `development` Gemfile group.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this slide show:

http://www.slideshare.net/drhenner/optimize-the-obvious-7636674

Might not be enough but it goes through some common faults.

Digging a little deaper take a look at this video:  http://windycityrails.org/videos2011/#2

It is longer but gives a lot of places to look.

On a different note.  Do you use a CDN?

Comment: Thanks, this is great. No I'm currently not using a CDN for my assets.